# Asp.NET label displays

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, label

So i have this .Net website which is very basic and simple since i am creating it to learn .Net and pratice. For the moment i have a form that after some inputs checks in the database and ant displays data. 
What i what now to do but im not figuring out yet how to do it is that:

If the system checks and there is no data equal to the input in the database the label posts a msg like: "NO DATA FOUND" 
Here is the code i used for checking and displaying data after clickin submit button:

```
protected void Search_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       try
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbconnect"].ConnectionString);
            con.Open();

            SqlCommand cnd = new SqlCommand();

            cnd.CommandText = "select * FROM [dbconnect] ";
            cnd.Connection = con;
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
            da.SelectCommand = cnd;
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds, " dbconnect ");
            SqlCommandBuilder cb = new SqlCommandBuilder(da);
            DataRow drow = ds.Tables["dbconnect"].NewRow();

            drow["userName"] = TextBox3.Text;
            drow["rollno"] = TextBox4.Text;

            ds.Tables["TableName "].Rows.Add(drow);
            da.Update(ds, " dbconnect ");
        }

        catch(Exception EX)
        {
            string A = "";
        }

}
```

how can i make my label to post a msg if from the button i will not have a response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add a Label control to your web page, say called lblMessage, then at the end of your code above, you could do something like...

```
lblMessage.Text = "No results found";
```

Comment: I think ther should be a IF clause as well. since i dont want to display it every time but just in case there is no data found

Comment: @Lara Yes there should. I was trying to concentrate on the answer to you specific question, ie how to display the result, however you are correct that you'd only want it to display if there weren't any results. If my answer is correct, please mark it as the right one and upvote as well.